# NServiceBus & deciding service boundaries

Tags: nservicebus, soa

I am a beginner at NSB and I have been looking for some kind of rule of thumb for deciding what constitutes as a separate service. Unfortunately I haven't found much online or in [David Boike's](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-nservicebus) book or on the [docs](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/) page.

The typical examples given are Sales, Shipping, Billing. So my original thinking is to divide according to real departments in a company, but what about things like Logging and other things that may fit into a 'fire and forget' model? Wouldn't having so many services increase the complexity? Is there a certain optimal number?

**what is a good rule of thumb for deciding what is a real service without going over the top?**

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow.  I would encourage you to post this question (with more detail) on the mailing list/forum for NServiceBus: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware.

Comment: This is indeed a good question contrary to what Phil said, this is a generic SOA question. The best way to set your services is to do use the departments in your company, but that isn't always possible, so the best to to is to discuss the services boundaries with the business, also have a look at DDD because that helps you define the boundaries the way you want. Also logging isn't a real service; you can have generic services, to send emails, sms, to archive documents as you would have a printer shared by two departments, but not logging.

Comment: I said it's not a good question for Stack Overflow--I did *not* say it wasn't a good question.

Comment: Go look at the BIAN and IFX service catalogue for a concrete example of how banks typically implement these types of services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging, security, and many other "cross-cutting" concerns are usually put together in an "IT/Ops" Service.

UI color schemes and layout are the responsibility of a Branding service.

Beyond that, it can be quite hard to find the right boundaries for services. Organizational structure can be tempting, but it is rarely precise - this being due to the relatively large amount of overlap in business responsibilities between departments.

Here's a video that might help give some more insight:

http://www.udidahan.com/2015/02/02/finding-service-boundaries-%E2%80%93-illustrated-in-healthcare/